# Cairo dock startup issues on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dock, cairo

Cairo Dock doesn't start on startup, I always have to start it automatically.

Comment: sorry if I didn't describe  the problem much clearer.  after installing ubuntu 15.04 version, I configured my cairo-dock to launch on system startup but it seems not to work. I always have to call it from the application menu any time the system restarts. It was not like that on the previous version. Any possible advice will be nice.

Comment: there is no output with ls ~/.config/autostart command but  ls -l .config/autostart produces  Total 0 output.

Comment: this is the output cairo-dock-cairo.desktop
                                     cairo-dock.desktop

Comment: Pleasure - I've answered it for future readers. Marking it as accepted may help them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved [in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613309/cairo-dock-startup-issues-on-ubuntu-15-04?noredirect=1#comment864284_613309):

> Run this command: `ls ~/.config/autostart` –  Tim
>
> There is no output with that –  nana
>
> Run this command: `ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep cairo` –  Tim
>
> The output: `cairo-dock-cairo.desktop` and `cairo-dock.desktop` –   nana
>
> Run this command cp /usr/share/applications/*cairo* ~/.config/autostart/ –  Tim

The issue was the launcher wasn't in the autostart folder. If this ever happens again, use the last two commands - just change `cairo` to a word from the name of the program that isn't starting. Command 2 is optional, but is sensible to check what you are copying.